# Laravel 5.2 failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: laravel-5

[image]

My group mates have an existing project it runs very fine in their computer but when i try to run it in my laptop, it will not read its linked CSS. what seems to be the problem?

the error in the cmd is this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use absolute path replace with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css\main.css') }}">
```

in your master blade layout.

Replace main.css with the name of your css file.

OR

Check security settings (Right click/Properties/Security)

[image]

Comment: Hi sir Thankyou for helping but we already tried that too sir ,  still it does not work

Comment: If they have Windows and you Linux, take care of case while Windows is case insensitive Linux is very case sensitive.

Comment: i am using windows7 sir

Comment: Last thought, make sure that those files have security rights that everyone could read them, and the path until them it also readeble for everyone.

Comment: how to make  it  readable for everyone sir? sorry if there is a lot of thing i do not know yet

Comment: On file/directory Right click/Properties/Security/Edit Add everyone and set Permissions.